# Fluent NHibernate - HasOne mapped to a ReferencesAny

Tags: nhibernate, fluent, has-one

I have the following POCO classes:

```
public class Container
{
    public virtual Int64 ContainerId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Location
{
    public virtual Int64 LocationId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UniqueLocation : Location
{
    public virtual Container Container { get; set; }
}

public class SharedLocation : Location
{
    public SharedLocation()
    {
        this.Containers = new List<Container>();
    }

    public virtual IList<Container> Containers { get; set; }
}
```

and the following Fluent mapping:

```
public class ContainerMap: ClassMap<Container>
{
    public ContainerMap()
    {
        Table("Containers");
        Id(x => x.ContainerId);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        ReferencesAny(x => x.Location).IdentityType<Int64>().EntityTypeColumn("LocationType").EntityIdentifierColumn("LocationId")
            .AddMetaValue<UniqueLocation>("U")
            .AddMetaValue<SharedLocation>("S");
    }
}

public class LocationMap : ClassMap<Location>
{
    public LocationMap()
    {
        Table("Locations");
        Id(x => x.LocationId);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class UniqueLocationMap : SubclassMap<UniqueLocation>
{
    public UniqueLocationMap()
    {
        HasOne(x => x.Container).PropertyRef(x => x.Location).ForeignKey("LocationId").Cascade.All().Constrained();
    }
}

public class SharedLocationMap : SubclassMap<SharedLocation>
{
    public SharedLocationMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Containers).KeyColumn("LocationId");
    }
}
```

The problem is HasOne() mapping generates the following exception: "broken column mapping for: Container.Location of: UniqueLocation, type Object expects 2 columns, but 1 were mapped".

How do I tell HasOne() to use/map both LocationType and LocationId?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Where conditions are not possible on Entity references except using Formulas. The design seems a strange because it would be nasty to change a unique Location to a shared location.

what you want can be done using:

```
Reference(x => x.Container).Formula("(SELECT c.Id FROM Container c WHERE c.LocationId = Id AND c.LocationType = 'U')");
```

But i would prefere

```
class Location
{
    ...
    public virtual bool IsUnique { get { return Container.Count == 1; } }
}
```